# How to use crontab to shutdown linux for every saturday 3PM

Tags: linux, cron, shutdown

Hi I want to create schedule on my Linux server to shutdown it every Saturday 5PM. How can I do it.

Comment: If you shut it down at 3PM, how are you going to shut it down at 5PM again? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck, or what was the error you couldn't resolve? Have you looked at the cron related `man` pages? Which ones?

Answer (score 2):

This entry in the root user `crontab`file is for 5PM:

`0 17 * * Sat shutdown -h now`

Depending on your security policy, you might not want to use root's `crontab`for this, but rather schedule this in the `crontab`of an administrator account which has the privileges to execute the `shutdown`command.

Comment: @guido you probably meant `0 15 * * Sat shutdown -h now`

Comment: The subject says 3pm, the question says 5pm, so you're both right, or both wrong.